# Cannot display image on flipview from JSON

Tags: c#, json, image, uwp, flipview

I have a JSON like this:
[image: JSON]

I want to show "image_url" data on flipview. But I have a problem, that only appears a border (the pictures do not appear) on flipview.

XAML:

```
<FlipView x:Name="listingImageFlipview" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="230" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Background="{x:Null}">
                            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid x:Name="content" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                        <Border x:Name="coverBox" Width="230" Height="160">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="images/IP-placeholder.png"/>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <Image x:Name="cover" Source="{Binding ImageURL1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened" Loaded="cover_Loaded" Loading="cover_Loading"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        </FlipView>
```

code:

```
try
                {
                    string urlPath = "http://..../listings/" + listingIdDetail.Text + ".json?module=listings&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        listingDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
                        RequestException();
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                    JsonObject groupObject1 = jsonData.GetObject();

                    JsonArray jsonGallery = groupObject1["gallery"].GetArray();
                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonGallery)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject3 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                        string imageUrl = groupObject3["image_url"].GetString();

                        ListingClass fileImage = new ListingClass();
                        fileImage.ImageURL1 = imageUrl;
                        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileImage.ImageURL1));
                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.Source = bmi;

                        listingImageFlipview.Items.Add(image);
                    }
```

How do I get the image can be displayed on flipview?

Comment: Can you share your JSON as text?

Comment: This is link of the one of the json: http://indonesia-product.com/api/v1/listings/337417.json?module=listings&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f

Comment: What is the content of imageUrl? Did you achieve to parse the JSON?

Comment: ImageUrl is from "image_url" data and my code for imageUrl is string imageUrl = groupObject3["image_url"].GetString();

                        ListingClass fileImage = new ListingClass();
                        fileImage.ImageURL1 = imageUrl;
                        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileImage.ImageURL1));
                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.Source = bmi;

Comment: Yes but did you achieve to assign it? What your debugger says?

Comment: Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ImageURL1' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'. BindingExpression: Path='ImageURL1' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='cover'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ID' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'. BindingExpression: Path='ID' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='cover'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')

Comment: Can you try without? `var bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));`

Comment: @aloisdg The image still can not be displayed on flipview